# Is there an Xcode Theme similar to Oblivion?

Tags: xcode, themes

I like the [Oblivion](http://www.rogerdudler.com/?view=theme&id=1) theme from Eclipse.

**Is there a similar theme for Xcode?**

Answer (score 0):

You do have the option of some themes in the preferences inside Xcode.

There are default ones and you can create your own. The colors and fonts are completely customizable and you can use the black background. You can then save and name it somehow.

I don't think that you're able to import some though...

Answer (score 0):

just go in **Xcode --> Preferences --> Fonts & Colors** and select the **Dusk** theme. It's very similar but you can also modify its colors as you wish.

Or you can visit [the collection of custom themes by hdoria](https://github.com/hdoria/xcode-themes) and choose one! Instructions are at the bottom page ;)